# Creating a graph using MBeans CompositeData in Zabbix

Tags: jmx, zabbix

I'm exposing CompositeData[] via a JMX from one of the services.  Data will be in the type like,

```
key1 : value 1 [String]
key2 : value 2 [Integer]
```

I am trying to consume this data in Zabbix. How can i generate a graph of key2 against key1 or table of key1 & key2.

Documentation doesn't have enough information around this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need those in separate items. Your keys should look similar to this:

```
jmx["bean","attribute.key1"]
```

Comment: Zabbix doesn't allow to add 'text' type which is key1 to be added to the graph. So in that case how can i use it as the x-axis.

Comment: Ah, didn't pick up the desire to put strings on a graph. Unfortunately, Zabbix does not support that at this time.